# transposing chunks of data in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, transpose

I have been struggling with his problem for so long and going back to excel and wasting a ton of time and energy.
I was hoping I could solve this problem in Matlab as i have a lot of data.
My instrument spits out data as follows:

```
TIME  PAR  ETS  
01:30  0     0  
01:30  40    300  
01:30  100   500
.  
01:30  1500 800
```

followed by the next time

```
02:30 0     0  
02:30 40    344  
02:30 100   653  
.  
.  
02:30  1500 1700
```

and so every hour or so I get a PAR vs ETS curve but all the data is stacked one below the other but I would have preferred that i had a file with one PAR column and each ETS column stacked by its side with the the time as header likewise:

```
PAR   01:30   02:30  
   0      0       0  
  40      300     344  
  100     500     653
.  
.  
1500      800    1700
```

I hope I was clear.
Would it be possible to do this in Matlab as I am a novice but I would like to start somewhere.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered looking at using Excel Pivot tables (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)? You could have `Time` as columns, `Par` as rows and `ETS` as values. Does the instrument populate the data in Excel or a CSV file? Also, it might help show us how you are reading the data into MATLAB?

Comment: Hi Azim, Thanks a lot for your response. No I have never used pivot tables but I could try. Currently I move the columns to the format i desire and then fit a curve through them with a matlab script that I got online. The instrument gives a text file. I use 'readtable' if that was your question.

Comment: Excel's Pivot Table feature can do what you need to do for pivoting the data. Yes, `readtable` partially answers my questions. Is the first column in the output of `readtable` a date/time column or text?

Comment: Also, is the `PAR` variable identical for each time period?

Answer (score 0):

If the values for `PAR` are identical for each time period (as they are in your example). Then you could use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`table/join`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.join.html) to build your transposed table.

First use `unique` to get the column names from the `time` column and the values for the `PAR` column. For example

```
T = readtable('data.txt');
var_names = unique(T.TIME); 
row_values = unique(T.PAR);
```

Next create a base table with the `PAR` values as the first column

```
pivotTable = table(row_values,'VariableNames',{'PAR'});
```

Now you can loop over the variable names using `join` to append these as variables to the base table. This loop will have the following elements

1. Select the rows for a specific `time` to create a sub-table for one set of `time` values
2. Set the tables `ETS` column name to the current `time` value. Note that time values suchas `01:30` are not valid variable names. So, you can use `matlab.lang.makeValidName` to convert these values to appropriate names for your table columns.
3. Use join to append this sub-table to the base-table

Here is an example of how this would work:

```
for v = var_names'
    selected_rows = strcmp(T.TIME,v{1});
    subTable = T(selected_rows,{'PAR', 'ETS'});
    subTable.Properties.VariableNames{2} =matlab.lang.makeValidName(v{1});        
    pivotTable = join(pivotTable,subTable);
end
```

Comment: Hi Azim, Thank you ever so much for your code which I was able to understand and run and my apologies for the delay in responding as I was away. So now that I have this new spreadsheet would you please help me to average the first two columns then the next two etc etc? I also would very much like to plot the first two column values and their averages so that I can see that they are close in values. My apologies but I have such a problem with loops. Thanks once again.

Comment: @fatima55, I am not sure what you mean by average the first two columns and then the next two??? You can get the average of columns (variables) in a table with `varfun` and `mean` as in `mean_values` = varfun(@mean,pivotTable);`. Would that work for you?

Comment: @fatima55: to plot a column such as column 5, use: `plot(pivotTable{:,5})` pay attention to the use of braces `{}`  as opposed to paretheses `()` in indexing the table.